# Acknowledgement of message received from rabbitmq queue using amqp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabbitmq, amqp

I am using `rabbitmq` with `amqp protocol` for chatting in my application. I want to get `acknowledgement` for message received to sender successfully.

**Created a channel**

```
channel  = AMQP.channel
```

**Created a queue on rabbitmq**

```
channel.queue(receiver_id, :auto_delete => false, durable: true)
```

**Channel fanout**

```
sender_exchange = channel.fanout(sender_id+"exchange")
```

**Channel publish**

```
channel.publish(message)
```

Now i want to get `acknowledged` for message received to sender using ruby on rails,let me know which method i use to get `acknowledgement`.

Answer (score 3):

The answer really depends on what "acknowledgement of message received" should mean in your application.  Here are two possibilities:

1. The message has been received by the broker
2. The message has been received by one or more consumers on the broker

In your chat feature, should this acknowledgement mean option 1 (the message made it from your client to the server) or option 2 (the message made it from your client to one or more other clients)?

[Confirms (Publisher Acknowledgements)](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html) is a feature of RabbitMQ that extends AMQP to confirm to a publisher that a message has been received by a broker.  This is probably the best solution for option 1.  It is probably not what you want for option 2 because it will confirm even if the message is not routed to any consumers.  See the "When will messages be confirmed?" section in the documentation linked above.

Option 2 is sort of like "read receipts" in an e-mail client.  It will require the receiver to send a receipt message once they've received and displayed the message.

To implement Confirms in rails, assuming you're using Bunny as your AMQP client, follow the Publisher Confirms example [here](http://rubybunny.info/articles/extensions.html).  It might look something like this:

```
# wherever I create my channel
channel.confirm_select

# publish my messages

channel.wait_for_confirms
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know when a message was received *by a consumer* (it doesn't sound like you're after knowing when it was received by the broker; if so, @Ryan Hoegg's answer will get you what you need), you'll need to do a highly asynchronous variant of the [RPC pattern](https://www.rabbitmq.com/direct-reply-to.html).

RPCs are usually synchronous: you send a command (via RabbitMQ queues in this case) and get a response back as soon as it's finished running. In the case of a "read receipt", the command might be executed a long time in the future.

If you stick with RabbitMQ, below is how you'd implement read-receipts conceptually. It'll require a fair amount more code, since RabbitMQ doesn't support this automatically/there's no primitive for "a long time later, see if something has been received". Read receipts can be implemented with one queue (and constant space; no backed up read-notification messages filling up RabbitMQ) per chat (pair of peers).

## General Pattern

Say Alice wants read-receipts from her messages sent to Bob.

1. Give each message a [monotonically increasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) numeric identifier. The first message is #1, second is #2 and so on. The `message_id` field in RabbitMQ is well suited for this purpose. Alice should manually "tag" each message with the increasing ID.

Example (Alice):

```
message_number = message_number + 1
sender_exchange.publish(message_body, :message_id => message_number)
```

2. Alice's client tracks "has Bob read my message?" by storing two numbers: the highest-numbered message Alice has sent, and the most recent message Bob has read. So if Alice's "read state" is 3, that means Alice has gotten confirmation that Bob has read messages 1, 2, and 3.
3. When Alice's client starts, it should declare a queue named uniquely for that conversation, `alice_bob_read_receipts` (or something corresponding to your `receiver_id` variable; so long as it's unique). Declaration should be idempotent/unconditional. That queue should be declared with an [`x-max-length`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html) of 1 and an `x-overflow` of `drop-head` (if on an older version of RabbitMQ, `x-overflow` may not be supported, but the default behavior will be what you want).

Example (Alice):

```
read_receipt_queue = channel.queue(
  "#{receiver_id}_#{sender_id}_read_receipts",
  :arguments => {
    "x-max-length".to_sym => 1,
    "x-overflow".to_sym => "drop-head"
})
```

4. When Bob reads a messages (e.g. by scrolling to it or opening the application), Bob's client should publish a message to the `alice_bob_read_receipts` queue with the read message's ID. The `correlation_id` RabbitMQ metadata field is intended for uses like this, so it can be used to store the message ID that Bob read.

Example (Bob):

```
read_receipt_queue = channel.queue(
  "#{receiver_id}_#{sender_id}_read_receipts",
  :arguments => {
    "x-max-length".to_sym => 1,
    "x-overflow".to_sym => "drop-head"
})
exchange = read_receipt_queue.default_exchange

# Assume we've got a list of messages Bob has "read" somewhere
# and each item in that list is the exact same triple as received
# by the Queue#consume method's block:
# http://rubybunny.info/articles/queues.html#handling_messages_with_a_block
viewed_messages.each do |delivery_info, properties, payload|
  exchange.publish("", :correlation_id => properties.message_id)
end
```

5. Alice's client should then subscribe to the read-receipt queue (since this can be done on a polling basis, you could skip the consumer logic if you want and just use `Queue#pop`, but that's less efficient and can block your program). If the consumer gets any data, Alice should set her "Bob has read messages up to this number" counter to the value received in the popped message's `correlation_id`, and then update the UI/read-receipt state. That update should only be performed if the received value is greater than the read-receipt state Alice knew about previously (since messages might get lost or redelivered).

Example:

```
read_receipt_queue.subscribe(...) do |delivery_info, properties, payload|
  if properties.correlation_id > known_messages_bob_read
     known_messages_bob_read = properties.correlation_id
  end
end
```

## Possible Enhancements

There are a few ways to improve the reliability and/or behavior of the "read receipt" pattern:

- The examples I gave all assumed that peers can store their last-sent-message and last-received-receipt numbers in a reliable database. If that's not possible, you have to abandon monotonic counters, and start over from a certain number each time a peer connects to the session. This works fine; your peers just have to be aware that they may see lower message numbers than they previously were aware of; you can detect the difference between out-of-order/retried message delivery with an unexpectedly-lower number and a reconnected client starting over with a low number by using a secondary client-session ID.
- If your message history is transient (disappears after each chat), or if you want to be *really sure* that reconnecting clients neither duplicate nor miss messages or read receipts, you'll need to have some sort of handshake negotiation between peers when a session first starts. That way, both peers can end up with a guaranteed-unique shared session ID. Since RabbitMQ sits in the middle of all this, you won't be able to use existing libraries (e.g. SSL) for this purpose, so you'll have to roll it yourself. If you do this, don't consider it a security feature (use real security in addition to it), just a state-synchronization feature.
- If your message history is *not* transient (all your messages are in a reliable database somewhere), it might pay off not to use RabbitMQ to synchronize read receipts at all. If you can store a "read or not" bit with each message, or a single-cell "max read message id" in the database, your clients can poll that database to update their read receipts. If polling is too slow or imposes performance penalties, you could use a read-receipt queue as mentioned in my examples, but with a fallback to the database when clients reconnected. Alternatively, the read-receipt queue could be used to reduce polling by just sending a "poll the database for a read notification" bit and not a counter.